# Odd top margin l in compact style of iMessage extension

Tags: xcode, imessage

I met a problem that there is a blank top margin in MSMessagesAppPresentationStyleCompact when from MSMessagesAppPresentationStyleExpanded.

I created my UIViewController from MSMessagesAppViewController, and called:

```
self.currentViewController = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"MainMenu"];
[self.currentViewController.view.leftAnchor constraintEqualToAnchor:self.view.leftAnchor].active = true;
[self.currentViewController.view.rightAnchor constraintEqualToAnchor:self.view.rightAnchor].active = true;
[self.currentViewController.view.topAnchor constraintEqualToAnchor:self.view.topAnchor].active = true;
[self.currentViewController.view.bottomAnchor constraintEqualToAnchor:self.view.bottomAnchor].active = true;
```

It works fine at initially and MSMessagesAppPresentationStyleExpanded. The problem will present when switch to MSMessagesAppPresentationStyleCompact again. There always have a blank top margin in it. Like:

[image]

How to fix it?[image]

Comment: I'm also having this issue, did you figure it out?